# what is alsa library read value meaning?

Tags: c++, alsa

I am reading sound values with alsa library and return some value like this 40239717. But I did not understand means. How to convert this value normal form.

My read code is like this:

```
if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
            qDebug("cannot open audio device default\n");
            exit (1);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&hw_params)) < 0) {
            qDebug ("cannot allocate hardware parameter structure\n");
            exit (1);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any (capture_handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
            qDebug("cannot initialize hardware parameter structure\n");
            exit (1);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access (capture_handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
            qDebug ("cannot set access type \n");
            exit (1);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format (capture_handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)) < 0) {
            qDebug ("cannot set sample format\n");
            exit (1);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near (capture_handle, hw_params, &sample_rate, 0)) < 0) {
            qDebug ("cannot set sample rate\n");
            exit (1);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near (capture_handle, hw_params, &frame, 0)) < 0) {
            qDebug ("cannot set sample rate\n");
            exit (1);
    }
    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels (capture_handle, hw_params, 2)) < 0) {
            qDebug ( "cannot set channel count\n");
            exit (1);
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params (capture_handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
            qDebug ("cannot set parameters\n");
            exit (1);
    }
    if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (capture_handle)) < 0) {
            qDebug ("cannot prepare audio interface for use\n");
            exit (1);
    }
    if ((err = snd_pcm_readi(capture_handle,buffer,frame)) != frame) {
                      qDebug("read from audio interface failed\n");
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are configuring the device for 16-bit samples (`SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE`).

The value `40239717` does not fit into 16 bits, so you obviously are using a wrong data type to read the `buffer`.
Ensure that `buffer` has the type `int16_t` or `signed short int`.